# Azure container instance run parameters

Tags: azure, containers

I want to run a container instance (OrientDB database). I created an Azure file share and attached it to the instance (had to use Azure CLI command-line interface since Web GUI doesn't support it). The problem is that I need to give in the run parameters to map internal folder to external one. I am searching for days and simply cannot find how to give in the parameters. I am sure I am not the only one doing this but everything I found was not satisfactory. Help anyone?

I am so far using this command.

```
az container create -g ProjectX --name orientdb --image orientdb:3.0.32 `
    --cpu 1 `
    --memory 1.5 `
    --environment-variables ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=*** `
    --os-type Linux `
    --ports 80 2424 2480 `
    --protocol TCP `
    --ip-address public `
    --dns-name-label *** `
    --azure-file-volume-share-name *** `
    --azure-file-volume-account-name *** `
    --azure-file-volume-account-key *** `
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /mnt/azurevolume `
    --restart-policy OnFailure
```

I don't know if "azure-file-volume-xxx" parameters are enough. I think not since I think these only attach the external volume to the container but performs no mapping.

And the command to run orientdb container locally is:

```
docker run -d --name orientdb -p 2424:2424 -p 2480:2480 \
    -v <config_path>:/orientdb/config \
    -v <databases_path>:/orientdb/databases \
    -v <backup_path>:/orientdb/backup \
    -e ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd \
    orientdb
```

Thanks
Tomaz

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work with these parameters:

```
--azure-file-volume-account-name
--azure-file-volume-account-key
--azure-file-volume-share-name
--azure-file-volume-mount-path
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

```
az container create \
    --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --name hellofiles \
    --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-hellofiles \
    --dns-name-label aci-demo \
    --ports 80 \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key $STORAGE_KEY \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name $ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /aci/logs/
```

PREVIOUS ANSWER (where I was guessing about the docker image and command line prameters the OP was using)

In a nutshell:

***Non*** "secret" aka sensitive values.  You use ENVIRONMENT variables to "inject" configuration values.

Note the "--environment-variables"

```
az container create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name mycontainer2 \
    --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-wordcount:latest \
    --restart-policy OnFailure \
    --environment-variables 'NumWords'='5' 'MinLength'='8'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables

Philosophically, you do NOT bake these values into your container.  You container "reaches out" to get them...the simplest way your container can "reach out" is to read an environment variable.

..

For secrets, you use Azure KeyVault.  This is outside the scope of your question, but I mention it so you avoid the bad security practice of using ENV variables for secrets.

Secrets would be "database passwords", "client_secret" for Oauth2, etc, etc.

Breadcrumbs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity

https://thorsten-hans.com/integrating-azure-keyvault-with-azure-container-services

Comment: Volume mapping is not really a secret and I also cannot find if there is a way to set it through environment variable. For the docker run, the parameters is i.e. "-v <databases_path>:/orientdb/databases". I guess this is not really an environment variable.

Comment: You should add all that information to the original question.    the docker image, your current docker call that sets the magic value...etc, etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  But please add all relevant information to your original question.